# Need help to migrating flutter project to another device

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I want to migrate my flutter project to my new pc, the android studio and flutter are all set in the new pc. If I make a new flutter project, it works fine, however, if I open the project from my old PC, It cannot detect the flutter library. Any suggestions?

[image]

Flutter doctor result
[image]

Comment: what is the output of `flutter docker` command in terminal  ??

Comment: you mean doctor? only missing Visual Studio component, the rest are green

Comment: yeah i mean `doctor`.. did you try  `flutter clean`  or `flutter clean -V` and  `flutter pub get` ?

Comment: did you installed plugins in vs code or android studio ?

Comment: i tried, but none of it worked @ShifaT

Comment: already installed @ShubhamNarkhede

Comment: share the output of this command flutter doctor -v  from your old PC

Comment: @HardikMehta I already edited it

Answer (score 1):

**Use this command**

**`flutter clean`**

**`flutter pub get`**

**`flutter packages get`**

**`flutter packages upgrade ( Optional - use if you want to upgrade packages )`**

**`Restart Android Studio or VS Code`**

**Hopefully the problem will be solved.**